# Asp.net quetions in login.aspx

Tags: asp.net

How to convert the below vb code to c#

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a id="A1" href=<%#"~/MemberPages/viewprofile.aspx?UserId="
        & Eval("UserId").ToString %> runat="server" >             
               <%#Eval("UserName")%></a><br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I tried the below but still showing the error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
Source Error:

```
Line 33:     <div style="padding-left:10px">
Line 34:     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
Line 35:     <ItemTemplate>        <a id="A1" href="~/MemberPages/viewprofile.aspx?UserId="+ '<%# Eval("UserId").ToString() %>' runat="server" >             
Line 36:                <%#Eval("UserName")%></a><br />    </ItemTemplate>
Line 37:     </asp:Repeater>


Source File: /WebSite1/login.aspx    Line: 35
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of VB vs C#. You're missing a double quote after `Eval("UserId").ToString %>`. It should actually use single quotes as in the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a id="A1" href='<%# String.Format("~/MemberPages/viewprofile.aspx?UserId={0}",
        Eval("UserId").ToString()) %>' runat="server" >             
               <%#Eval("UserName")%></a><br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
    <ItemTemplate>        
<a id="A1" href="~/MemberPages/viewprofile.aspx?UserId='<%# Eval("UserId").ToString() %>'" runat="server" >
```